# vert.x OAuth2 Facebook API call to get access_token fails because of text/plain content type

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, vert.x, vertx3

Facebook seems to answer some API calls with text/plain instead of application/json. The oauth endpoint https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token is one example. This seems to confuse the vert.x oauth client implementation. This is the call that fails:

```
oauth2.getToken(new JsonObject()
                        .put("code", code)
                        .put("redirect_uri", callbackUrl),
                res -> {
                    if (res.failed()) {
                       logger.warn(res.cause().getMessage());
                    } else {
                       AccessToken = res.result();
                       // ...etc...
                    }
```

The logged message is: `Cannot handle content type: text/plain`

So my question is, apart from the obvious solution of implementing my own `getToken()` method just for the Facebook provider, is there any other way to make the implementation parse the plain text response? It is a simple url encoded string like `access_token=foo&expires=5179336`

Is there a way to make Facebook answer in JSON that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Use a newer version of the Facebook API. In v2.3 they changed the format of oauth/access_token to return JSON.

So https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token and https://www.facebook.com/v2.7/oauth/access_token will return JSON in the format `{"access_token": {TOKEN}, "token_type":{TYPE}, "expires_in":{TIME}}`.

If you or the SDK you're using is using the uri https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token then it's using the v2.0 API instead of the current version.